# How to use "Thread" classes?

Tags: android, multithreading

How do you use "Thread" classes? A most basic example would be great!

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you want to do with the Thread class? You might want to look into an `AyncTask` instead: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: i tried with services but i couldnt find out how to use a listener, i tried with asynctask but i couldnt instantiate my database, so now i want to try threads :( and i find google's documents are very hard to follow

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Thread myThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        // Do Stuff
    }
});

myThread.start();
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to use thread class.
One is directly used in the function.
The Runnable class is the job to do.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() 
{
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        //Do things.
    }

}).start();
```

Another is create a new class and extend the thread interface.

```
public class MyThread extends Thread
{
    public void run() 
    {
        //Do things. 
    }
}
```

You may refer to the article [How to use thread in Android](http://ibuzzlog.blogspot.tw/2012/07/how-to-use-thread-in-android.html).